# How to fix Table Headers at the top using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want my Table Headers to be fixed at the top and I am using `Position: sticky;` in thead
but they remain fixed only halfway through the scrolling and after that they move along with it.

This is what I have done

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="scroll-table">John</td>
            <td class="scroll-table">Doe</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS I am using

```
table thead{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

I want the thead to stick at the top during Scrolling

Comment: post html too with snippet `<>` so we can replace with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply this values for the `th` elements instead of `thead`:

```
table th {
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
}
```